# homeomorphism $\Rightarrow$ isomorphism ? (counterexample, Hartshorne exercise 3.2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I "had solved" a tedious exercice showing that two varieties are isomorphic. I "had solved" this by proving that there was a homeomorphism between the underlying topological spaces (with the Zariski topology).

Now, I just came across Hartshorne exercise 3.2 which provides counterexamples where homeomorphism does not imply isomorphism. So my conclusion was unjustified, even though my exercise doesn't deal with pathological cases.

Since I spend a lot of time figuring out this exercise (and I don't want to throw everything away), I was wondering if there was some extra condition which I could check in order to deduce the result, i.e.

"homeomorphism + Extra Condition $\Rightarrow$ isomorphism"

Comment: Homeomorphism doesn't tell you much at all. For example, any two (irreducible) algebraic curves (projective or otherwise) over a fixed algebraically closed field are homeomorphic.

Comment: And what if I have also proven (= part a. of the exercice) that there is an isomorphism between their rings of regular functions? Is this somehow useful (together with the constructed homeomorphism) to deduce an isomorphism?

Comment: @Reply to myself: Yes, but only in the affine case, right?

Comment: How do you prove this in the affine case?

Comment: oh, but not every homeomorphism is an isomorphism

Comment: @edo_arad (#1): It's a big theorem in my course notes. The theorem shows that there exist an equivalence between categories $\mathcal{O}$ and that it is possible to reconstruct affine $k$-sets from their algebra of regular functions.

Comment: As Zhen Lin points out, this is pretty hopeless, without going the full way of requiring your homeomorphism be a morphism of ringed spaces. The topology on varieties is so coarse, that you get almost nothing by saying that two curves are topologically the same (as Zhen Lin points out, any two irreducible curves are homeomorphic since they are all equipotent and carry the cofinite topology). The topology can't even tell between compact and non-compact (in the usual topology) for complex varieties.

Comment: Actually, the next exercise in this book says the ‘extra condition’ is that the induced map $\phi_P^*$ on local rings is an isomorphism for all P in X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a category we say that a morphism is an isomorphism if it has a (two-sided) inverse $in$ $that$ $category$.  In your case the category is algebraic varieties over a fixed field, and morphisms are algebraic maps.  The real problem is that even if your algebraic map has an inverse in the category of topological spaces (i.e. is a homeomorphism) there is no reason a priori that the inverse map should be algebraic. Intuitively, and in the affine case what you should ask is "does the inverse function involve taking roots?" if so it's not an algebraic map.

What exactly the "extra condition" is much more transparent in the context of schemes instead of varieties, there in addition to the underlying topological space we have the extra data of a structure sheaf.  The condition for a morphism of schemes to be an isomorphism is that the underlying map of topological spaces is a homeomorphism and the corresponding map of sheaves is an isomorphism.